# Using a server to host mail servers and redirect website requests to another server

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy

I have 2 servers. At my registrar, the DNS of my domain points to Server1.
How can I set up my servers, so that Server1 redirects all Web requests for my domain to Server2.

My goal is that I can change Server2 whenever I want without having to change the DNS at my registrar (and have to wait X hours for the changes to spread). I would simply change something in Server1 so that it redirects to Server3 instead of Server2 and as soon as I would do that, it would work for all visitors.

Does it make sense? How would I set this up? I looked at DNS servers and slaves but I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the below line to the `.htaccess` file on server 1 so that it redirects all http requests to server 2.

```
Redirect 301 / ip-address-of-server-2
```

Comment: Thanks, Webmaster. I am on Windows server. If I do a 301 redirect using the IP address, it looks like the address showing up in the web browser becomes http://ip-address-of-server-2 and not the domain anymore. Also the domain on server 2 is on a shared IP and the request does not get funneled to the proper domain...

Comment: I found a similar question that may have an answer for you: http://serverfault.com/questions/47537/can-iis-be-configure-to-forward-request-to-another-web-server. Also, you may read this article to get specifics for IIS 5 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313074

Comment: Thanks, Webmaster. Indeed I believe what I am looking for is a reverse proxy. Thanks!